# VB.NET How to check if a string follows a format

Tags: vba, vb.net

what i'm looking for is a way for a way to check if a string follows a specific format. 
Something Like:

```
if strPhoneNumber = format(XX-XXXX-XXXX) then
      MsgBox("Correct")
else
      MsgBox("Incorrect")
```

the specific format is Two Numbers, a Dash, Four Number, A Dash, Four Numbers: eg: 04-9567-3915
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse [a Regular Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), so use a regular expression:

```
Dim regex As New Regex( "\d\d\-\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\d\d" );
If regex.IsMatch( strPhoneNumber ) Then

    MsgBox("correct")

End If
```